# Measure Theoretic Probability: convergence almost surely

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $A_{nm}(\epsilon)=\{|Z_k-Z|<\epsilon,\ n\leq k\leq m\}$. Show that $Z_n\to Z$ with probability $1$ if an only if $$\lim_n\lim_m P(A_{nm}(\epsilon))=1$$ for all positive $\epsilon$, whereas $Z_n\to_P Z$ if and only if $\lim_n P(A_{nn}(\epsilon))=1$ for all $\epsilon$.

Trying to figure out this problem, any thoughts?

> - $Z_n\to Z$ converges with probability $1$ means that $$P(\{\omega:\ Z_n(\omega)\to Z(\omega)\})=1$$
> - $Z_n(\omega)\to Z(\omega)$ means that $\forall k, \exists M$ such that $\forall n>m\; |Z_n(\omega)-Z(\omega)|<\frac{1}{k}$
> - $Z_n\to_P Z$ if for all $k$, $\lim_n P\left(|Z_n-Z|\geq \frac{1}{k}\right)=0$.
> - Of course, $P\left(|Z_n-Z|\geq\frac{1}{k}\right)=1-P\left(|Z_n-Z|<\frac{1}{k}\right)=1-P\left(A_{nn}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What is the definition of almost sure convergence and convergence in probability?

Specifically, can you verify both directions of the below biconditionals?

$$\lim_n \lim_m P[A_{nm}(\epsilon)]=1\iff \forall \epsilon>0, \exists n: |Z_k-Z|<\epsilon\; \forall k>n$$

and

$$\lim_n P[A_{nn}(\epsilon)]\iff \forall \epsilon>0, \lim_k P(|Z_k-Z|<\epsilon)=1$$

Does knowing one side of each of these allow you to derive the other side?

**Example: LHS of Biconditional 1**

Fix $n$:

$$\lim_m P[A_{nm}(\epsilon)]=P(|Z_k-Z|\leq \epsilon\;\forall k>n)=f_n$$

But, we are assuming:$\forall \epsilon>0,\lim_n f_n =1$ (do you see that the sequence of $f_n$ are monotonic in $n$?)

Also, this assumption results in:

$$\forall \epsilon>0,\lim_n f_n = 1 \implies \forall \epsilon \exists n: |Z_k-Z|<\epsilon\;\forall k>n $$ by the definition of a limit.

This also happens to define almost sure convergence.